# Pre-requisites for Service pack installation on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, servicepacks

I am having a service pack installation on one of my production server of SQL Server 2012. Before proceeding to install i need to have clear idea about what are the pre-requisites and steps we need to consider for smooth service pack installation on prod SQL Server.
If In case services pack fails where can we see the particular error related to that.

please let me your thoughts

Regards

Comment: I think this is a good place to start: http://www.littlekendra.com/2016/04/28/required-testing-for-installing-sql-server-cumulative-updates-and-service-packs/

Comment: And this: http://sqlserverupdates.com/frequently-asked-questions/